# General Behavior of Euler Totient Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, totient-function

If we have two integer M and N such that

$$GCD(M,N) = k$$

Then what is

$$\phi(MN)$$

There is a famous identity which states:

$$GCD(M,N)= 1 \rightarrow \phi (MN) = \phi(M)\phi(N)$$

And now I am curious about generalizing this result to other numbers. Is there any literature on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gcd(m,n)=k$.   Then the following identity is valid:

$$\varphi(m\cdot n)=\varphi(m)\cdot\varphi(n)\cdot\frac{k}{\varphi(k)}$$
If you want to learn more about Euler's totient function you could have a look [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86)